# How to interpret SCSI device (sd) timeout logs

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, devices, syslog, scsi

In /var/log/messages, I find the following log:

```
Oct 23 21:48:53 localhost kernel: sd 3:0:0:0: timing out command, waited 180s
```

Please explain the values that are separated by colons.

Also where does 180s come from?  Is this user definable?

Also how do you know which SCSI command timed out?

Answer (score 2):

(thanks to @dirkt for the answer)

The 3:0:0:0 is the SCSI Address.  See http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/SCSI-2.4-HOWTO/scsiaddr.html.

Also see command 'lsscsi'.  It lists each SCSI device in the system, and its corresponding SCSI address.  So you can match up the error log with the SCSI device.

Comment: If you don't happen to have the `lsscsi` command installed, `lsblk -o +HCTL` will achieve the same thing. (HCTL refers to Host-adapter, Channel, Target, LUN: the four digits separated by the colons).